# Regex for [key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3],[key21:value21,key22:value22]

Tags: java, regex

I want to check whether a given String matches the following format:

```
[key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3],[key21:value21,key22:value22]..
```

There may be 1 or more [.*] tokens (separated by comma) and inside [] brackets we can have one or more key:value  pairs.
I used:

```
(\\[(.*:.*)+(,*)\\]+),*
```

but unfortunately it passes for:

```
*[key1:value1][key2:value2] (comma is missing between [] tokens)
*[key1:value1][invalid] (second token was invalid format)
```

Can you help me to improve the regex above?

Comment: Like this [`^\[\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*\](?:,\[\w+:\w+(?:,\w+:\w+)*\])*$`](https://regex101.com/r/J7w95i/1)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 characters to which you could hold on: colon `:` and comma `,`

So you could define your keys and values as: `[^:,]+` (one or more of any character, except colon and comma).

And a key-value pair would be then: `[^:,]+:[^:,]+`

Here is [my test program](http://ideone.com/dVvPCF):

```
private static final String GOOD_1 = "[key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3],[key21:value21,key22:value22]";
private static final String GOOD_2 = "[key1:value1],[key21:value21]";
private static final String GOOD_3 = "[key1:value1]";
private static final String BAD_1 = "[key1:value1],[key21]";

private static final String KEY_VALUE = "[^:,]+:[^:,]+";
private static final String TOKEN = "\\[" + KEY_VALUE + "(," + KEY_VALUE + ")*\\]";
private static final String REGEX = TOKEN + "(," + TOKEN + ")*";

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("REGEX is " + REGEX);
    System.out.println(GOOD_1 + " is " + check(GOOD_1));
    System.out.println(GOOD_2 + " is " + check(GOOD_2));
    System.out.println(GOOD_3 + " is " + check(GOOD_3));
    System.out.println(BAD_1 + " is " + check(BAD_1));
}

private static boolean check(String str) {
     return str.matches(REGEX);
}
```

If you run it, you will get the output:

```
REGEX is \[[^:,]+:[^:,]+(,[^:,]+:[^:,]+)*\](,\[[^:,]+:[^:,]+(,[^:,]+:[^:,]+)*\])*

[key1:value1,key2:value2,key3:value3],[key21:value21,key22:value22] is true
[key1:value1],[key21:value21] is true
[key1:value1] is true
[key1:value1],[key21] is false
```

However if your input data is in JSON format, then you shouldn't waste your time by trying to create a regular expression for it. Pass it to [a JSON parser](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/json-1973242.html) instead.